# Python/Selenium - confirmation pop up accept

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

any ideas on a confirmation box that pops up?  As I've worked through this, I know the code is switching to the alert box - but the trackback error seems as though I need a different method - other than 'accept'.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Environment: Python 37.32/Selenium 2.33

```
dscopy = browser.find_element_by_name('_eventId_discontinueAndCopy')
dscopy.click()

time.sleep(3)
alert = browser.switch_to_alert
alert.accept()
```

(Trackback)
erap.py", line 57, in 
    alert.accept()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'accept'

Comment: are you sure is it alert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke the `switch_to_alert`!

```
dscopy = browser.find_element_by_name('_eventId_discontinueAndCopy')
dscopy.click()

time.sleep(3)
alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

**EDIT:**

As [@Corey Goldberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16148/corey-goldberg) commented:

Switch_to_alert is deprecated so you should use:

```
alert = browser.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: switch_to_alert is deprecated

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I'll Edit that in... The correct way is `switch_to.alert.accept()`?